# CALENDAR API : Event list is different each time i execute it

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

I have a problem, each time I execute my code to retrieve calendar list, then my events.

calendar list is always the same, however the Events number is different each time I execute the code.

there is a start date and end date, here is my code.

````
        // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({})
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                 let data = JSON.parse(response.body);

                for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
                         let calendar_id = data.items[i].id;
                         getEvents(calendar_id, function() {
                                 if(i == data.items.length -1) {
                                         addInvoices(Invoices);
                                         console.log(Invoices);
                                 }
                         });
                       
                 };
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }

       
  function getEvents(calendar_id, callback) {
          let start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
          let end_date = new Date($('#end_date').val());
          console.log(start_date);
          console.log(end_date);
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                 'calendarId': calendar_id,
                 'timeMax': end_date.toISOString(),
                 'timeMin': start_date.toISOString(),
                 'showDeleted': false,
             'singleEvents': true,
                 'orderBy': 'startTime'
         })
                .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            let events = response.result.items;
                        for(let m = 0; m < events.length; m++) {
                                if(!Invoices.includes(events[m]) )
                                        Invoices.push(events[m]);
                        }
                   callback();
            return events;
           },
                          function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err);});
  }

  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "{{ $currentCompany->getSetting('client_id') ? $currentCompany->getSetting('client_id') : '' }}"});
  });  ``` 

Do you have any idea why i got this issue ?
````

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we do not add "FIXED" to the title of the question. Simply answer the question (preferably with more detail) and accept the answer (once the appropriate time has elapsed).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, error was in my ajaxcontroller.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.